# Why does Arraylist hold object rather than reference variable, as opposed to Array holding reference variable or primitives?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZrow.png)When I'm learning array's knowledge, there are such descriptions saying array holds reference variables(not object itself) or primitives, as opposed to `ArrayList` holding an object. I want to confirm why `ArrayList` can hold object rather than reference variables. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et8bx.png)

Comment: "remember that a reference variable just holds a reference" ... why do you forget that when reading the second image? I don't see the point in writing "Arraylist holds an arbitrary amount of reference to objects stored in the heap" instead of just "Arraylist holds objects" when every one (at least should) know what it technically means.

Comment: when you do ***list.add(999)*** internally java does: ***list.add(new Integer(999))***

Comment: An ArrayList is a wrapper for an Object[] so they behave exactly the same. "why arraylist can hold object rather than reference variables" - it can't.

Comment: To say that a variable, an array element, an `ArrayList` element, etc., "holds an object" is non-strict, less verbose, informal usage that should always be understood as meaning "holds an object **reference**".

Comment: I think so , but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're just taking everything out of context...

if you would read further in the second image then you'd understand that there exists primitve arrays (`int[]`) but no such thing as a primitive List (`List<int>`).

Instead you have to use wrapper classes (`List<Integer>`).

Then don't mess up the definition of `Object` and `Object reference` because in java you never can have an `Object` in place, you're always working with `Object-references` (and also with `primitives` to be really clear).